# Setup jenkins to use gitBucket git repository

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, gitbucket

I'm creating a Maven project inside Jenkins. The maven project need to get the source from a git repository hosted in GitBucket. Jenkins and GitBucket are running on different Windows server and are running inside Tomcat webservice.

I found different pages and tutorial to setup this up but without any luck.
When I try the same command in the cmd everything works like it should be.

My error that I got when running the Jenkins job looks like:

```
09:47:05 Building in workspace D:\Jenkins\workspace\CR-IT server
09:47:05  > D:\Applications\ThirdParty\x64\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
09:47:05 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
09:47:05  > D:\Applications\ThirdParty\x64\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url http://airsbeap0658/gitbucket/git/air27654/CR_IT_Platform_Server.git # timeout=10
09:47:05 Fetching upstream changes from http://airsbeap0658/gitbucket/git/air27654/CR_IT_Platform_Server.git
09:47:05  > D:\Applications\ThirdParty\x64\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
09:47:05 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
09:47:05  > D:\Applications\ThirdParty\x64\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress http://airsbeap0658/gitbucket/git/air27654/CR_IT_Platform_Server.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
09:57:05 ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
09:57:05 ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
09:57:05 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from http://airsbeap0658/gitbucket/git/air27654/CR_IT_Platform_Server.git
09:57:05    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:806)
09:57:05    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1066)
09:57:05    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1097)
09:57:05    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
09:57:05    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
09:57:05    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
09:57:05    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
09:57:05    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
09:57:05    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
09:57:05    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
09:57:05    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
09:57:05    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
09:57:05 Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "D:\Applications\ThirdParty\x64\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress http://airsbeap0658/gitbucket/git/air27654/CR_IT_Platform_Server.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
09:57:05 stdout: 
09:57:05 stderr: 
09:57:05    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1784)
09:57:05    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1513)
09:57:05    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
09:57:05    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
09:57:05    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:804)
09:57:05    ... 11 more
09:57:05 ERROR: null
09:57:05 Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the repository url in my Jenkins configuration to include the user and password.

> http://USER:PASSWORD@host/...